# Actionscript 3 Movieclip To Repel The Mouse Cursor

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, cursor, mouse

I'm trying to build an application where the themouse cursor is used to "blow" a movieclip around. The way I'm doing this is by making the mouse cursor repel the movieclip.

The problem is, I can only get it to work on the top and the left of the movieclip.

Here's my code:

```
function moveCloud(event:Event):void {

var yChange:Number = Math.round(mouseY-cloud.y);

var xChange:Number = Math.round(mouseX-cloud.x);

//var yMove:Number = Math.round(yChange);

//var xMove:Number = Math.round(xChange);

var dist:Number = Math.sqrt(xChange*xChange + yChange*yChange);
trace(dist);
if(dist < 100)
{
 var angle:Number = Math.atan2(yChange, xChange);
    cloud.y += Math.cos(angle)*2;

    cloud.x += Math.sin(angle)*2;
}
```

Anyone done something like this before or have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change sine and cosine and substract it instead of adding.

```
cloud.x -= Math.cos(angle);
cloud.y -= Math.sin(angle);
```

Comment: @Patrick Great! Then you should also check this as the right answer.